# PDF/TIFF Document Text Detection

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ocr, python-3.6, google-cloud-vision

I am currently trying to use Google's cloud vision API for my project. The problem is that Google cloud vision API for document text detection accepts only Google Cloud Services URI as input and output destination. But I have all my projects, data in Amazon S3 server which cant be directly used with this API.

Points to be noted:-

1. All data should be in kept in **S3** only.
2. I can't change my cloud storage to **GCS** now.
3. I can't download files from **S3** and upload to **GCS** manually.The number
   of files that are incoming per day is more than 1000 and less than
   100,000.
4. Even if I could automate downloading and uploading of the pdf, this
   would serve as a bottleneck for the entire project, since I would have to deal
   with concurrency issues and memory management.

Is there any workaround to make this API work with S3 URI? I am in need of your help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Vision API doesn't work with URLs, apart from the Google Cloud Storage ones. There's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72421411) for the image search related to use the API with specific URLs where you could ask to consider this feature for the PDF/TIFF documents too, or raise a new [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010835) for this scenario.